# Make the sidemenu slide OVER the form in Codename One

Tags: menu, codenameone

The current behavior of the sidemenu in Codename One is that the sidemenu pushes the current form aside as it comes out. I need to have the sidemenu slide over the form without displacing it instead.

It appears that the only options are to modify the underlying code for the sidemenu or to utilize some other component in a way that would mimic sidemenu behavior. From a conversation I had with CN1 support, modifying the underlying code sounds problematic and I haven't been happy with the results thus far of layering other components on top of the form.

Has anyone else been able to successfully implement this functionality? if so, can you please share how it was done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hope we can do that for you but scheduling is making this really challenging. If all else fails try avoiding the sidemenu altogether and using a `Container` in the layered pane or alternatively a full blown `InteractionDialog` to simulate a sidemenu.

Comment: This seems like a common request and I couldn't manage to get it to work, got stuck on the animation.

Comment: Which one, the sliding with the finger down or the transition?

Comment: The transition of the sidemenu to slide over the form.

Comment: And did you override the inner class that implements that transition effect? Notice that there are several separate places in that code that do the same thing in different ways both because of the difference between finger drag/transition but also for performance on the devices (using mutable image vs. drawing directly). You need to change all of these places which isn't trivial